# data lookup from web service isn't displayed correctly in label

Tags: ios, swift, label

I have two calls that are being made to web services which I am attempting to display in a label on a secondary view.

First lookup or call occurs during the load of the main view controller as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
getAddress()
}

func getAddress() {
    let URL_GET_ADDR:String = "http://www.webserver.com/apps/getmailingaddr.php"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_GET_ADDR)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in
        //exiting if there is some error
        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }
        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            //var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
            self.teamJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            //getting the JSON array teams from the response
            let address: NSArray = self.teamJSON["mailing"] as! NSArray

            //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
            for i in 0 ..< address.count{

                //getting the data at each index
                let addrName:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["name"] as! String!
                let addrAddr1:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary) ["address1"] as! String!
                let addrAddr2:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["address2"] as! String!
                let addrCity:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["city"] as! String!
                let addrState:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["state"] as! String!
                let addrZipcode:Int = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["zipcode"] as! Int!
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I am passing this data to the contacts view controller with the following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let ContactsViewController = segue.destination as? ContactsViewController {
   ContactsViewController.myAddress = teamJSON
}
```

All is good so far.  Now in the contacts view controller I am performing a lookup of the contacts with the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   myLabel = ""
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   contactsLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
   //created NSURL
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_GET_TEAMS)
    //creating NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
    //setting the method to post
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in
        //exiting if there is some error
        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }
        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
            teamJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            //getting the JSON array teams from the response
            let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["contacts"] as! NSArray
            //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
            for i in 0 ..< teams.count{
                //getting the data at each index
                let teamId:String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary)["title"] as! String!
                let teamName:String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary) ["name"] as! String!
                //displaying the data
                //print("id -> ", teamId)
                //print("name -> ", teamName)
                //print("===================")
                //print("")
                self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<font size='5'><b>" + teamId + "</font>:</b> " + "<font size='5'>" + teamName + "</font><br /><br />"
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: self.myLabel.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            self.contactsLabel.attributedText = attrStr
            self.contactsLabel.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()

    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: myLabel.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    contactsLabel.attributedText = attrStr
    contactsLabel.sizeToFit()
    getAddress()
}
```

The getAddress function call here takes the data that was passed in and adds it to the label:

```
func getAddress() {
    //getting the JSON array teams from the response
    let address: NSArray = myAddress["mailing"] as! NSArray
    //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
    for i in 0 ..< address.count{

        //getting the data at each index
        let addrName:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["name"] as! String!
        let addrAddr1:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary) ["address1"] as! String!
        let addrAddr2:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["address2"] as! String!
        let addrCity:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["city"] as! String!
        let addrState:String = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["state"] as! String!
        let addrZipcode:Int = (address[i] as! NSDictionary)["zipcode"] as! Int!

        let myCityStateZip : String = addrCity + ", " + addrState + " " + String(addrZipcode)

        let myName : String = addrName + "<br />" + addrAddr1 + "<br />" + addrAddr2

        let myDescription : String = "*All Correspondence for the Board / Assoc.<br /> should be directed to the following address:<br /><br />"

        self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<b><font size='5'>" + myDescription + "</font></b>"
        self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<font size='4'>" + myName + "</font>"
        self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<font size='4'>" + myCityStateZip + "</font>"
        self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<br /><br />"

        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: myLabel.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        contactsLabel.attributedText = attrStr
        contactsLabel.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Here is the problem, first time through it works perfectly displays the data correctly and in the correct order.  If you go back out and then back into the contacts page, the address ends up at the top of the label with the contacts following.  I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone have an explanation why?

Comment: Still waiting to see if someone can provide a reasonable answer to this or a solution to the problem.

Comment: Anyone out there have an answer to this?  It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I even moved the address func call to viewWillAppear and set the label text value to blank at the start of the viewDidLoad but its still acting the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move both lookups to the front end (main view controller's viewDidLoad function) and pass them as values to the second controller.  That way your second controller only has to be concerned with formatting the data for display.